# Как фильтровать строки по значению словаря?

Tags: python, pandas, словари, анализ-данных, фильтрация

Есть таблица из файла CSV, в которой один из столбцов - словарь. В каждой строке у словаря может быть свой набор ключей.

Пример:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 
                   'dict':[{'05': '123', '21': 'w', '14': 'z'},{'05': 'ft6v', '14': 'z'},{'05': 'gtr', '09': 'r', '14': 'n'}
                           ,{'05': 'e434q', '21': 'r', '18': 'z'},{'08': '143hk4qyt', '21': 'r', '18': 'z'}]})
```

Необходимо создать отдельный столбец, в котором будет для каждой строки значение по ключу '05' из словаря по этой строке (при отсутствии - ноль). И затем выбрать только строки, в которых значение ключа '05' состоит из трех символов.

В идеале должна получиться таблица:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 
                   'dict':[{'05': '123', '21': 'w', '14': 'z'},{'05': 'ft6v', '14': 'z'},{'05': 'gtr', '09': 'r', '14': 'n'}
                           ,{'05': 'e434q', '21': 'r', '18': 'z'},{'08': '143hk4qyt', '21': 'r', '18': 'z'}],
                 'is_05':['123','ft6v','gtr','e434q','0'],
                    'is_05_3':['1','0','1','0','0']})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df["is_05"] = df["dict"].map(lambda x: x.get("05", "0"))

df["is_05_3"] = df["is_05"].str.len().eq(3).astype("int8")
```

---

результат:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  id                                       dict  is_05  is_05_3
0  a        {'05': '123', '21': 'w', '14': 'z'}    123        1
1  b                  {'05': 'ft6v', '14': 'z'}   ft6v        0
2  c        {'05': 'gtr', '09': 'r', '14': 'n'}    gtr        1
3  d      {'05': 'e434q', '21': 'r', '18': 'z'}  e434q        0
4  e  {'08': '143hk4qyt', '21': 'r', '18': 'z'}      0        0
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Kate, всегда рад помочь)